# Problema al ejecutar funcion ajax por 2da vez vez en chrome y safari sin recargar la página

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-chrome, safari

Hola tengo una situación un poco rara y me gustaría que me dijeran si es tema de compatibilidad de los navegadores u otra cosa.La cuestión es la siguiente.Tengo una vista que muestra una tabla,tengo un campo de tipo `file` que me importa registros desde un `excel` y cuando este se importa vía `ajax` relleno la tabla, el tema es que desde `chrome` o `safari` cuando importo una vez y luego quiero volver a importar no se ejecuta el código `javascript` que llama a la función `ajax` que me envía los datos del `excel` al servidor,visualmente no hace nada la pagina, para volver a importar datos tengo que recargar la página,sin embargo esto no me ocurre con `firefox`,con este importo cuantas veces quiera sin recargar la página y la tabla se llena perfectamente.mi codigo javascript es el siguiente.
    $('#excel input[type="file"]').on('change', function () {

```
    $('.preview_locales, .preview_locales_overlay').fadeIn();


    // validar xls
    var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var regex = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(xls|xlsx)$");

    if(!(regex.test(val))) {
        $(this).val('');
        $('.preview_locales, .preview_locales_overlay').fadeOut();
        alert('El formato de archivo es incorrecto.');
    } else {


        // nombre formulario
        $('#excel input[name="id_local"]').val($('#id_local').val());
        $('#excel input[name="id_dac"]').val($('#id_dac').val());
        $('#excel input[name="tipo"]').val($('#tipo').val());
        $('#excel input[name="id_dac_pdv"]').val($('#id_dac_pdv').val());
        $('#excel input[name="id_ejecutivo"]').val($('#id_ejecutivo').val());
        $('#excel input[name="id_bodega"]').val($('#id_bodega').val());
        $('#excel input[name="id_ubicacion"]').val($('#id_ubicacion').val());


        var form = $('#excel').get(0);

        var fd = new FormData(form);

        //fd.append('id_local', $('#id_local').val());

        //console.log(fd);
        fd.append("user_", "This is some extra data");
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.php?route=chips/lista/importar&token=" + token,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: fd,
            success:function(json){

                if (json.status == 1) {
                    lista('busqueda');
                }

                $('#mensaje').html(json.mensaje);
                $('.preview_locales, .preview_locales_overlay').fadeOut();

            },
            error:function(data){
                $('.preview_locales, .preview_locales_overlay').fadeOut();
                alert('Ha ocurrido un error.');
            }

        });




    }
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te sugiero que uses la consola del navegador para ver que respuesta trae en eso casos que mencionas success:function(json){....console.log(json);..}

Comment: es que ni siquiera hace una petición eso es lo raro..incluso le pongo un alert() en el evento on onchange y despues de haber ejecutado una vez el importar a la 2da vez que trato de hacerlo nisiquiera sale el alert...

Comment: probe adjuntando un fichero diferente y si ejecutó la petición,asi que el problema parece ser que debo resetear ese input cada ves que realice la peticion

Comment: entonces deberias establecerlo a null algo asi $("#mi_input").val(null);

Comment: ya solucione el problema muchas gracias

Comment: como lograste solucionar este problema?

Comment: Sería bueno que publiques tu solución como respuesta y la aceptes. Eso servirá a otros que tengan situaciones similares. **Nota**: En el primer manual de ajax, que leí (hace bastante tiempo) recomendaban agregar a la url un parámetro **pseudoaleatorio** para que el navegador interprete todas las solicitudes como diferentes y garantizar que las envíe: algo del estilo `urldesolicitud?rompecache=valorrandom` esa solicitud siempre será procesada por el mismo controlador, pero siempre será distinta y el parámetro se ignora en el servidor.